# Why can't I create a directory named CON?

Tags: python, python-3.x, path

I was trying to create a directory if it does not exists yet using the built-in `pathlib` from Python. My code looks like this:

```py
Path("./src/CON").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

However, I am running into this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\main.py", line 16, in <module>
    Path("./src/CON").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
  File "C:\Users\wangy80\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\pathlib.py", line 1284, in mkdir
    self._accessor.mkdir(self, mode)
NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'src\\CON'
```

The thing I don't understand is that if I replace `CON` with any other folder name it works perfectly (I am generating thousands of folders but only `CON` gives me an issue). There are no duplicated folders too. Why is this the case?

I'm on Windows10 running Python 3.8.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This was answered in the official Microsoft community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/why-cant-i-create-a-folder-with-con-name/23c86662-4988-4c7d-9c2d-3e33d4413de3):

> You can't make folders on the desktop that have "System Action" or
> "Device"  references such as con, nul and prn. Solution is to use
> another name or use 0 instead of o,O for C0n.